# Pick up from last line in vimrc

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc file, how can I make it so that when I tab in X amount of times about (let's say 3) that when I hit return, it'll also be tabbed in 3 times?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want... aren't you just searching for "3."? . is repeating the last action.

Comment: @PhilippMehrwald Not searching for anything. Just wanting to pick up from the position of the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set ai
```

`ai` is auto-indent

To disable auto-indent:

```
:set ai!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. As kotlinski below suggested was what I was previously using, it was giving a weird format to my js code. Thanks this works great.

Comment: `set option!` does not disable an option, it toggles the state of a boolean option.  To explicitly disable autoindent `set noai`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough... `set smartindent`

Comment: I had that before, but that formats my javascript in a weird/annoying way.